# Vectorization of MATLAB code to optimize speed

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Hey fellow MATLAB users. The following code is meant to analyze motion in films. However, when I run the script on a film, it takes almost 14 hours for MATLAB to run the code. I have heard that you can optimize running speed by vectorizing your code; however, I have no idea how to go about this with the code below, since I am far from a programmer.

Can anyone help me out, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot – the m.code is as follows:

```
 %calculates correlations in sequences of film shots   22 May 2014
     %t = input vector of initial frames of all shots in the film

 prompt1 = 'movie file = ';
 movieavi = input(prompt1,'s');

 mov = VideoReader(movieavi);

 nshots = length(t)-1;

 for n = 1:nshots
     first = t(n);
     last = t(n+1)-2;
     slength = last - first + 1;
     tempcor = 0;

 for k = 1:(slength-1)
     im1 = read(mov,first+k-1);           %read the image
     im2 = read(mov,first+k+1);
     im1 = rgb2gray(im1);               %convert to grayscale
     im2 = rgb2gray(im2);
     tmp = corr2(im1,im2);
     if(isnan(tmp) == 1) 
        tmp = .9999;
     end
     tempcor = tempcor + tmp;
 end

 dataout(n,3) = tempcor/(slength-1);    %mean Lag 1 correlation within a shot
 dataout(n,1) = uint32(first/100);      %frame in hundreds. Can't export 6 digit integer
 dataout(n,2) = mod(first,100);         %modolus 100, to be combined with above

 cycle = t(n)

 end;

 xlswrite('dataout.xls', dataout) %this file appears in matlab folder and must 
 save dataout;                    %the Matlab version of same
```

Comment: I think the best you can do save the frames from `k-1` to `k+1`. Further vectorization seems unlikely.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to find out what's taking the most time?